# Msg 245, level 16, State 1, Line 58 Conversion Failed when Converting this varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey guys I am trying to add to my inserts for my athlete the team names however for some reason I keep getting an conversion errors that says: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQapx.png)

I have two tables one being a teams table and the other is athlete table, I have added the Foreign Key to the athlete table but now I am trying to get the athelete insert show the team names, but it provides me the error. How would I fix this? my teamId is an INT and I need to make it into a Varchar correct since I am trying to insert strings not numbers..

[Team Table & Inserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAXfP.png)

[Athlete Table & Inserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCkmJ.png)

For the athlete inserts I added the team names this is why it gives the error. Please help. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE team(
    teamId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    teamName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamCity VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    teamState CHAR(2),
    teamCountry VARCHAR(6),
    teamManager VARCHAR(50),
    teamLeague CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    teamStadium VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_team_teamId PRIMARY KEY (teamId)
);

    INSERT INTO team
VALUES
    ('Toronto Blue Jays', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'Canada', 'Charlie Montoyo', 'AL', 'Rogers Centre'),
    ('Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago', 'IL', 'USA', 'Rick Renteria', 'AL', 'Guaranteed Rate Field'),
    ('Tampa Bay Rays', 'Tampa Bay', 'FL', 'USA', 'Kevin Cash', 'AL', 'Tropicana Field'),
    ('Colorado Rockies', 'Denver', 'CO', 'USA', 'Bud Black', 'NL', 'Coors Field'),
    ('Los Angeles Angels', 'Anaheim', 'CA', 'USA', 'Joe Maddon', 'AL', 'Angel Stadium of Anaheim'),
    ('New York Yankees', 'New York', 'NY', 'USA', 'Aaron Boone', 'AL', 'Yankee Stadium'),
    ('Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', 'USA', 'Derek Shelton', 'NL', 'PNC Park'),
    ('Cincinnati Reds', 'Cincinnati', 'OH', 'USA', 'David Bell', 'NL', 'Great American Ball Park');
GO

    CREATE TABLE athlete(
    athleteId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    athleteFirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    athleteLastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    athleteDateOfBirth DATE,
    athleteHeight SMALLINT,
    athleteWeight TINYINT,
    athletePosition CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    athleteBattingAvg DECIMAL(4, 3) DEFAULT 0.000,
    athleteNationality VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamId INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_athlete_athleteId PRIMARY KEY (athleteId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_teamId FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES team(teamId)
);
DROP TABLE athlete;

    INSERT INTO athlete (athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, athleteDateOfBirth, athleteHeight, athleteWeight, athletePosition, athleteBattingAvg, athleteNationality)
VALUES
    ('Vladimir', 'Guererro Jr.', '1999-03-16', 188, 113, '3B', 0.272, 'Canada', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Bo', 'Bichette', '1998-03-05', 183, 83, 'SS', 0.311, 'USA', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Cavan', 'Biggio', '1995-04-11', 188, 90, '2B', 0.234, 'USA', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Travis', 'Shaw', '1990-04-16', 193, 104, '1B', 0.157, 'USA', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Danny', 'Jansen', '1995-04-15', 188, 104, 'C', 0.207, 'USA', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Randal', 'Grichuk', '1991-08-13', 188, 96, 'OF', 0.232, 'USA', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Teoscar', 'Hernandez', '1992-10-15', 188, 92, 'OF', 0.230, 'Dominican Republic', 'Toronto Blue Jays'),
    ('Tim', 'Anderson', '1993-06-23', 185, 83, 'SS', 0.335, 'USA', 'Chicago White Sox'),
    ('Jose', 'Abreu', '1987-01-29', 190, 115, '1B', 0.284, 'Cuba', 'Chicago White Sox'),
    ('Kevin', 'Kiermaier', '1990-04-22', 185, 95, 'OF', 0.228, 'USA', 'Tampa Bay Rays'),
    ('Nolan', 'Arenado', '1991-04-16', 188, 97, '3B', 0.315, 'USA', 'Colorado Rockies'),
    ('Mike', 'Trout', '1991-08-07', 188, 106, 'OF', 0.291, 'USA', 'Los Angeles Angels'),
    ('Aaron', 'Judge', '1992-04-26', 201, 127, 'OF', 0.272, 'USA', 'New York Yankees'),
    ('Giancarlo', 'Stanton', '1989-11-08', 198, 111, 'OF', 0.288, 'USA', 'New York Yankees'),
    ('Joey', 'Votto', '1983-09-10', 188, 99, '1B', 0.261, 'Canada', 'Cincinnati Reds');
```

Comment: You did not specific what columns your inserting, so you insert the first column is text and you are trying to insert that into an INT column (your ID).  Also do not post screen shots post code please

Comment: I tried adding the column names to the inserts but still the same error

Comment: Code is TEXT, please copy/paste text into the question and format it. We cannot copy/paste bits of images into an answer and very few are going to recode your code

Comment: Also please TAG a database any database but only the one database you are actually using. TAGS are used to gather the correct audience for your question, so spamming them will only get you downvotes

Comment: Sorry guys I just fixed it, I added the code into text, apologies

Comment: If you DROP your `athlete` table before loading and querying it, you are not going to get anything but an error message

Comment: Yes i commented it out apologies, sorry im new to SQL

Comment: Specify column names for the `team` table insert

Answer (score 0):

You declared `teamId INT` in the `althlete` table.

But when you load data to the table you are loading an INT column with

```
'Toronto Blue Jays'
```

You should be loading that column with the id value from the `team` table that will have been generated in the previous table load

Comment: I see, but am i not trying to have it output the names of the team for the athletes. so would I use teamID?